# Creating an XY graph in labview which would store previous values

Tags: arrays, graph, labview

Link to the vi: [see xy_plot_problem_withcase](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fimuv7u8q7p9ue2/kE9jB1jl3X)

In the attached vi (xy_plot_problem_updated.vi) I am able to get 3 individual values x, y and z in an array, element 0 being x, element 1 being y and element 2 being z.

These three values come for every iteration of the outer while loop. I would like to store all generated x values into one array and same with y and z so I can use the final arrays to generate one final graph.

The outer while loop runs 30 times and I would like to record the 30 different values generated at index 0 in a separate array. I tried using a shift register, build array etc but its just replacing element 1 (of the new array) with the newest element generated (They are not getting accumulated).

I have encountered this problem while designing for a system which records 3 different readings for every 5 degree increase in temperature. I want to be able to plot the acquired values against the current temperature. Hence, the outer while loop is actually a case statement which gets triggered every time the temperature goes up by 5 degrees.

I have also attached the main VI too alongside (final.vi).

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the block diagram?

Answer (score 1):

In your final.vi you have a while loop, you should move everything in the case into the while loop. My advise for you would be to look at the LabVIEW fundamentals on data flow and on shift registers.
In your code you were resetting the shift register in the while loop every iteration.

Try to clean up your code and use the executing highlighting function (the light bulb).